# What verb is applicable for "prescription tablet/pills consumption"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

Consider the hypothetical expression,

> I fell sick, because I was slacking on my thyroid's pill consumption.

"Consumption" as a noun feels very awkward to me, can somebody suggest an alternative idiomatic expression?

Comment: One way to say it in the UK would be, "I got ill because I forgot (or kept forgetting) to take my thyroid pill."

Comment: *...because I didn't follow my thyroid pill [recommended] **dosage** [instructions]*. Where [**dosage**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dosage) is *The size or frequency of a dose of a medicine or drug.*

Answer (score 2):

"Slacking on **taking my thyroid pill**" would be a less formal alternative.

"my thyroid's pill consumption" doesn't really sound right, because it sounds like the pills belong to your thyroid, or that your thyroid is taking the pills by itself.  If you want to use a construction like this, it would work better as "my thyroid pill consumption", using *thyroid* as a modifier for *pill* and *thyroid pill* as a modifier for *consumption*.